# Working code won't execute after .load() but will execute other code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Could someone help me understand why this won't work? My button doesn't work after `.load()`.

For context, my HTML is just a div `(#box)` with a scrollbar and two buttons, one to refresh `(#load)` and one to scroll bot `(#scroll)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      Ref();
    });

function Ref() {
      $('#load').click(function() {
        $('#box').load('test.php #box', function(r, status){
          if(status == "success"){
            $('#scroll').click(function() {
              $('#box').scrollTop($('#box')[0].scrollHeight);
            });
          }
          else{
            console.log("Error");
          }
        });
      });
    }
```

The tags are correct and my `.load()` function works but the code after that just stops working.

**However, this does work:**

```
function Ref() {
      $('#load').click(function() {
        $('#box').load('test.php #box', function(r, status){
          if(status == "success"){
            console.log("Success");
          }
          else{
            console.log("Error");
          }
        });
      });
    }
```

On `.load()`, a success message is received in the log implying to me that it **DOES** load successfully, however once I put in my own scroll code it doesn't work and I don't receive any errors.

I've tried to debug it with console.log() but I didn't receive anything useful and I'm still new with jQuery so I don't get what's going on with my original code because it functions correctly outside of `.load()` and documentations tell me this should work as intended as a callback function.

Comment: Well, your code doesn't work. What you expect it to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: Also, in cases like this we actually need to see all relevant HTML as we cannot recreate your AJAX request